# Using threading to load things in the background

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame

I'm working on a tycoon game that allows users to buy upgrades and receive more in game money from them, however I realised I need threading to be able to implement this and started to get myself familiar with it by creating a loading screen that loads the users data and progress while showing a relatively true progress bar.

Everything went perfectly with the design for the loading screen, even the progress bar was working, then I moved on to actually starting to load data into variables and that's when it went wrong!

I've had a look at a bunch of questions like this on stack but have found no solution. Its not exactly code breaking but it makes it unreliable and occasionally won't load anything.

So here's the code in all its glory:

```
loader = threading.Thread(target=load)
loader.start()

i=0

with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    
print(len(data))
```

Yep! That's it! Those 6 lines of code are the only cause for a lot of problems!
Anyway, my issue is that for some reason the code loops so I get an output of:

```
pygame 2.0.0.dev8 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.8.3)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
..... (the 0's go on for a while)
```

The only print statement is the `print(len(data))` and the loop for the loading screen is is in a function that shouldn't be affecting the print statement at all.

So what's going on here and how can I fix it?

Full Code:

```
import Classes
from Constants import *
import pygame
import time
import threading
import json

def load():
    pygame.init()
    
    width = 720
    height = 1232
    
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    while True:
        screen.fill(LOAD_CLRS[0])
        
        text = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
        
        uuid= text.render(f"UUID:{UUID}", True, C_UUID[0], C_UUID[1])
        
        textRect = (0.05, height*0.95, width*0.3, height*0.1)
        
        screen.blit(uuid, textRect)
    
        boxpos = (width*0.147, height*0.697, width*0.703, height*0.053)
    
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, LOAD_CLRS[1], boxpos)
        
        print(i)
        
        loaderpos = (width*0.15, height*0.7, width*0.695*(i/100), height*0.047)
        
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, LOAD_CLRS[2], loaderpos)
    
        pygame.display.update()


UUID = ""

loader = threading.Thread(target=load)
loader.start()

i=0

with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    
print(len(data))
```

*EDIT: Theres nothing in `Classes` and only colours in `Constants`

Comment: You have a `print(i)` in the loop.

Comment: @ArvinKushwaha Yes, yes I do! D':

Comment: Turns out I'm just stupid and left a print statement in the loop by accident, although it didn't come up when I searched for it. Use this as a reminder to always check your code!

Comment: This code is putting the main PyGame Event loop into a thread.  It's best to keep the event loop in your main thread, and then start other threads for things like loading, printing, network comms, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of OT but you should lock the thread.start() call inside an if-statement to ensure that the thread does not restart itself for whatever reason, just a good redundancy

```
loader = threading.Thread(target=load)
if not loader.is_alive():
    loader.start()
    time.sleep(1) # From import time - To make sure the thread has time to start!
```

Comment: Also I know its a little off topic but seeing as though you've mentioned threads, how do I stop a thread without stopping the entire program?

Comment: As far as i know there are no ways to outright kill a thread in python, but you could always join it to the main thread by calling thread.join() but i can't say if that will work for what you're doing 

Check out the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html